# Расширение для Chrome которое добавляет объект на все веб страницы

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, manifest

Пытаюсь создать расширение для Chrome которое должно добавлять белый квадрат на все вновь открытые вкладки.  Расширение установилось, ни каких ошибок нет. Но добавление объекта не происходит.

Манифест

```
{
    "manifest_version": 3,
    "name": "White Square Extension",
    "version": "1.0",
    "permissions": ["activeTab", "scripting", "tabs"],
    "background": {
      "service_worker": "background.js"
    },
    "host_permissions": [
      "http://*/*",
      "https://*/*"
    ]
  }
```

background

```
chrome.tabs.onCreated.addListener((tab) => {
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
        target: {tabId: tab.id},
        files: ["/js/content.js"]
    });
});
```

Он в свою очередь должен вызвать срабатывание content.js

```
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var whiteSquare = document.createElement("div");
    whiteSquare.style.position = "fixed";
    whiteSquare.style.top = "0";
    whiteSquare.style.left = "0";
    whiteSquare.style.width = "20px";
    whiteSquare.style.height = "20px";
    whiteSquare.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    document.body.appendChild(whiteSquare);
  });
```

Сам скрипт работает, если его вызывать просто на странице.
Где я свернул не туда?